# how can we connect a2billing back to asterisk?

Tags: php, asterisk, freepbx

Dears,

the scenario that I am trying to accomplish is to connect a2billing back to asterisk [freepbx ] , since I have configured inboud routes that I want to use for some special numbers [ like toll free ] ,

the question is how can we use the inbound routes that we have configured before on the freepbx side

-- Adding what is done so far

I have defind a trunk from the provider , and from there I added inbound routes based on cid , and so far so good , and from a special did , I mapped to a2billing using custom-destination , and from there ,  I want to reuse the inbound routes after authenticating the card

Regards,

Comment: please post what you've done so far, and you will get suggestions based on that

Comment: @horace_vr , I added what is done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dears,

I have made a little adjustment to the code to check for special prefix and when I receive that by checking the destination in the code , I do a query to the inbound route to get the mapped phone number

Regards,